# How would I select certain values in a column in one table that is not available in a another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
**A    B    C    D    E**
  1    2    3    4    5
  2    3    3    3    3
  3    4    5    6    7
  4    5    5    5    5
```

I have another table that looks like this:

```
**F     G    H    I    J**
  1     4    7    8    6
  2     3    4    5    6
  5     1    5    7    8
  7     1    5    5    5
```

I will call the first table Table1 and the second table Table2.

What I'm doing currently is:

```
Select 
ts.B
from Table1 ts, Table2 tt
WHERE ts.A = tt.F
and NOT IN (Select tt.F from tt)
```

So, basically I'm joining Table1's A and Table2's F. I'm finding the values that do not are in A but not in F. And then I want to return the B value that corresponds with those A values.

I'm getting an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Your description on the requirement is a bit confusing. Maybe you can show us your expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT 
    t1.B
FROM
    dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.Table2 t2
        WHERE t1.A = t2.F
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT ts.B
FROM table1 ts
LEFT JOIN table2 tt ON ts.A = tt.F
WHERE ts.A IS NULL;
```

Comment: This one Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
ts.B
from Table1 ts, Table2 tt
WHERE ts.A = tt.F
and NOT IN (Select tt.F from tt)
```

In the above query

> NOT IN
>   Clause has been used but not include the resulting column from the table.

```
ColumnName NOT IN (Select tt.F from tt)
```

You can use a Left/Right outer join clause and check for NULL value in the appropriate column on where clause.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, your query is wrong here:

```
WHERE ts.A = tt.F
and NOT IN (Select tt.F from tt)
```

The fact that you already mentioned `ts.A` does not mean the parser "remembers" it. When it comes to the `and NOT IN`, it doesn't know *which thing* should be NOT IN. Id est, the correct way would be:

```
WHERE ts.A = tt.F
and ts.A NOT IN (Select tt.F from tt)
```